# Match/find row and color all line with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse csv output and find the row "Down" and change that line in red.I am n00b in Python and  I want to keep just Python code and not mix up with bash, awk or something else.I will provide you below my entire "project".

**1. My csv file - output_cisco** looks like:

```
198.22.21.2  interface Ethernet 47 Up 0
198.22.21.44 interface Ethernet 48 Up 0
198.22.21.21 interface Ethernet 49 Up 0
198.22.21.23 interface Ethernet 50 Up 0
198.22.21.22 interface Ethernet 51 Up 0
198.22.21.33 interface Ethernet 52 Down 0
198.22.21.17 interface Ethernet 55 Up 0
198.22.21.19 interface Ethernet 56 Up 0
198.22.21.20 interface Ethernet 57 Up 0
198.22.21.45 interface Ethernet 60 Up 0
198.22.21.66 interface Ethernet 61 Down 0
198.22.21.27 interface Ethernet 72 Up 0
198.22.21.26 interface Ethernet 73 Up 0
```

2. **My simple python code** looks like:

```html
#!/bin/env python
import re
import csv

filename = open('output_cisco')
for test in filename:
        new_line = test.replace("\n","")
        if (re.match('[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}]',new_line)):
                print new_line.split()[0], \
                      new_line.split()[1], \
                      new_line.split()[2], \
                      new_line.split()[3], \
                      if new_line.split()[4] == Down:
                                print("\033[0;31;47m %s ") % (new_line.split()[4])
                      else:
                                print("\033[0;32;47m %s") % (new_line.split()[4])
```

But I am stuck into red color condition, I tried many solutions and paths and still not working, and I have the following error:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/python# python python_parsing.py
  File "python_parsing.py", line 13
    if new_line.split()[4] == Down:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: A syntax error is often above the marked line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, this should work:

```
filename = open('output_cisco')
for test in filename:
    new_line = test.replace("\n","")
    if (re.match('[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}]',new_line)):
        print(new_line.split()[0], end=" ")
        print(new_line.split()[1], end=" ")
        print(new_line.split()[2], end=" ")
        print(new_line.split()[3], end=" ")
        if new_line.split()[4] == 'Down':
            print("\033[0;31;47m {} ".format(new_line.split()[4]), end="")
        else:
            print("\033[0;32;47m {} ".format(new_line.split()[4]), end="")
        print('\033[0;0;0m')
```

If you're using Python 2, this other version should work:

```
filename = open('output_cisco')
for test in filename:
    new_line = test.replace("\n","")
    if (re.match('[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}]',new_line)):
        print(new_line.split()[0]),
        print(new_line.split()[1]),
        print(new_line.split()[2]),
        print(new_line.split()[3]),
        if new_line.split()[4] == 'Down':
            print("\033[0;31;47m %s") % (new_line.split()[4]),
        else:
            print("\033[0;32;47m %s") % (new_line.split()[4]),
        print('\033[0;0;0m')
```

Also, you might need to tweak the last print statement a bit to get the colors back to "normal".

Comment: Hi there, 
It works, thank you so much for your help, I have python 2.7 install on my server.

Comment: if I have "03:30:20" instead of "Down" status how can I do to print red color?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it : if (re.match('[0-9]{1,2}:\d[0-9]{1,2}:\d[0-9]{1,2}',new_line.split()[4])):